# React: How to change Table cell background depending on cell value in React table

Tags: css, reactjs, react-table, reactstrap

I'm using reactstrap to build my table and im using axios to post and get my data from my backend.

I want to be able to change de background color of the cell (   ) depending on the value of the cell.

For example, if the cell value is < 0.25 background green if the cell value is less than 0 background red.

My current code looks like this:

```js
//Input sending data and Calling API back
  state ={
  data: []
}
//this gets triggered on line 85
  search = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    //Here we send the input that we add on line 90 value to Flask
    axios.post("/results",{search_question: document.getElementById("buscar").value})
    //Then we call it back
    .then((res) => {
      // console.log(res.data)
      //We create data variable with our returned data
      const data = res.data
      //Empty variable to pass all values from data
      const question = []
      // for loop that goes into data and pused everything to questions variable.
      for(var i in data)
        {question.push(data[i])}
      //console log to make sure our API returned the correct data and we saved in question
      console.log(question)
      //creating the state of paa and selecting the second index in question
      this.setState({paas:question[1]})

    })
     

    }

render() {

    //empty variable and set is a state
    const{paas = []} = this.state
    return (

<Table>
                    <thead>
                      <tr>
                        <th>Question</th>
                        <th>Sentiment</th>
                        <th>Magnitud</th> 
                      </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>

                {paas.length ? paas.map(paa => (
                  
                    <tr>
                      <td key="Questions" style= {{}}>{paa.Questions}</td> 
                      <td key="Sentiment">{paa.Sentiment}</td>
                      <td key="Magnitud"> {paa.Magnitud}</td>
                    </tr>
                   
                  ))
                :
                (<p> </p>)
                  
                      }
                       </tbody>
                 </Table>) }
      </Container>
  </div>
```

Also is this the right way fo serving tables? or should I use something different?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use a ternary operator and pass a class or value in

```
<td key="Questions" className={value > 0.25 ? 'greenclass' : 'redclass' }>
```

or

```
<td key="Questions" styles={{ background: value > 0.25 ? 'green' : 'red' }}>
```

---

Update for 3+ classes

I would use an outside function where you have an if/else or switch statement return className

Have this function outside the render

```
resolveClass = (value) => {
    let className = ''

    switch (true) {
        case (value > 0.25):
            className = 'green'
            break;
        case (value < 0):
            className = 'red'
            break;
        default:
            break
    }

    return className
}
```

Then inside the render `<td key="Questions" className={resolveClass(paa.Questions)}>`

Comment: What would value be here? {paa.Questions}??

Comment: If thats the number value that you want to check is greater than 0.25 then yes just change value to `paa.Questions`

Comment: Great. It works perfectly. How can I add a 3 class something like an elseif? like if its between 0 and 0.25 ?? Thank again

Answer (score 1):

You can do this like by two ways:

**By using css class (recommended):**

```
<td key="Questions" className={(paa.Questions == 'value_to_compare') ? 'css_class': null}>{paa.Questions}</td>
```

**By using conditional style:**

```
 <td style={(paa.Questions == 'value_to_compare') ? {textAlign:'center'}: {}}></td>  // Here instead of textAlign:'center' you can use your style
```